# How can I save images from reddit's image feeds (like CityPorn) to my Dropbox using IFTTT?

Tags: images, dropbox, rss

I want to save images from various Reddit feeds to my Dropbox so I can have a screensaver that automatically updates with new content.

IFTTT (If this then that) has settings to save images from RSS feeds, and reddit feeds can be displayed at RSS, but I can't figure out how to set up IFTTT to download the high-res images from these feeds into a dropbox folder.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the feed from Imgur - just append imgur.com with a /r//rss to see the rss for any image based subreddit using the Imgur service. All you have to do then is set up RSS trigger in IFTTT to upload to a folder in dropbox